# I am trying to encircle a part of back ground image with a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to encircle a part of back ground image with a div, but when window resizes it all becomes messed up, and I need it to display the same way on different screen sizes.
I am using google chrome

thank you for any ideas..

EXAMPLES

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

HTML

```
<div class="stage1">
    <div class="theRoom">
        <div class="table items"></div>
        <div class="picture items"></div>
        <div class="bookstore items"></div>
        <div class="door items"></div>
        <div class="makeup items"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.items {
        border: 2px solid red
}

.items:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 6px red);
    /*    background-size: contain;*/
}

.stage1 {
    width: 1960px;
}

.theRoom {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.table {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0000_table.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 78.7%;
    top: 54%;
    width: 296px;
    height: 424px;
    z-index: 6;
}

.bookstore {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0001_bookstore.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 64.6%;
    top: 33.3%;
    width: 243px;
    height: 462px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.door {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0002_door.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 217px;
    height: 421px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.makeup {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0003_makeup.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-size:contain;
    left: 30.7%;
    top: 46.3%;
    width: 9.7%;
  height: 299px;

    z-index: 3;
}

.picture {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0004_picture.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9%;
    top: 39%;
    max-width: 123px;
    max-height: 217px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.items {
        border: 2px solid red
}

.items:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 6px red);
    /*    background-size: contain;*/
}

.stage1 {
    width: 1960px;
}

.theRoom {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.table {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0000_table.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 78.7%;
    top: 54%;
    width: 296px;
    height: 424px;
    z-index: 6;
}

.bookstore {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0001_bookstore.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 64.6%;
    top: 33.3%;
    width: 243px;
    height: 462px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.door {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0002_door.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 217px;
    height: 421px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.makeup {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0003_makeup.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-size:contain;
    left: 30.7%;
    top: 46.3%;
    width: 9.7%;
  height: 299px;
    
    z-index: 3;
}

.picture {
    background-image: url("../img/room/room_0004_picture.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9%;
    top: 39%;
    width: 123px;
    height: 217px;
    z-index: 2;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>THE ROOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="script/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!--    <img src="img/The-master-bedroom.jpg" alt="" class="room">-->

    <div class="stage1">
        <div class="theRoom">
            <div class="table items"></div>
            <div class="picture items"></div>
            <div class="bookstore items"></div>
            <div class="door items"></div>
            <div class="makeup items"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="script/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello George! Welcome to StackOverflow! It would help your question if you add the browsers and devices you're having trouble with, and screenshots if possible; many browsers work slightly differently from each other and not everyone here will have a similar setup to you. Thanks!

Comment: it would also help if you posted it on codepen or something like that. The SO code snippet feature is pretty useless when it comes to responsive stuff.